# Parallel processing with Rcpp function - would I get less overhead using foreach or using RcppParallel?

Tags: r, c, rcpp

I have an Rcpp function which I am calling from R. I have made this parallel by using the 'foreach' package.

However, based on some brief experiments, the parallel computation is only worth it when the Rcpp function takes at least 0.1 seconds to evaluate.

For my project my function usually takes longer than 0.1 seconds to evaluate, and therefore the parallelisation is "worth it" in most cases. However there are some datasets where the function will take less than 0.5 seconds to evaluate, and it doesn't benefit from parallelisation due to the overhead of the 'foreach' package.

However, it would still be useful if there was a way that it could benefit from being run in parallel even when it takes < 0.1 seconds to evaluate, since the function needs to be evaluated many times.

So - my question is, in general, will making an Rcpp function parallel via C++ (using e.g. RcppParallel package) instead of via R (through foreach) create less overhead? or should I expect the same amount of overhead?

Comment: The best way to find out may be to measure.  But _ex ante_:  nothing in life, or on computers, is entirely free. So the (untested) answer is 'maybe not'.  Rcpp can give you some speed advantages over R.  It changes little with respect to, say, `parLapply()`.  Now, RcppParallel may be able to give you speedup over package parallel as it deals with things at the compiled level.  It is also more work.

Comment: Thanks very much for the info @DirkEddelbuettel - My Rcpp function is quite complicated and involves Eigen matrices, std::vectors containing Eigen matrices, and nested for loops - will it all have to be re-coded to work with RcppParallel or (generally) are the changes needed to make a function work with RcppParallel relatively minor?

Comment: No not that easy -- see the docs for RcppParallel you want to be careful to stay away from R memory that could get `gc()`ed. Could still be worth it. _Really_ difficult to guestimate _ex ante_.

Comment: Ah I see, I was hoping it would just be a matter of putting the Rcpp function around some other "container" function to make it work with RcppParallel without having to make any changes to the core function itself.... might still attempt to give it a go though

Comment: You can for some tasks -- the so-called 'embarassingly parallel' ones that are fully independent can just use your package as such and run in parallel. Think, say, of two (or more) long bootstrap sims under different parameterisations.  Those happily run at the same time in a 'shared nothing' setup.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Sorry if I am misunderstanding but don't all functions for parallel computations need to be independent whilst they are running in parallel? if I am running my function with K threads in parallel i only need to combine the results across the K runs at the end, and I keep repeating this for N iterations (I know it would be less overhead if I just started the K parallel processes first and then did the N iterations all in parallel - rather than having to launch K parallel tasks N times - however there are reasons why I cannot do that which are beyond the scope of this post).

Comment: What I outlined works on fully distinct memory objects. What RcppParallel does, _ex ante_, is to share some to split work and that is where your rewrite may come.  So in answer to your question I pointed to a more fully separate approach / class of problems not needing that.  We cannot say much more at this point with the info given.

Comment: I see... from what I gather from your comments I think my function falls under the "embarrassingly parallel" category, so it may not require any major re-write